# Cannot find MavensMate -> Settings --> Users

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I am using Windows 10.

I got Sublime Text 3 installed.

I installed MavensMate v0.0.11-beta.7.

I am trying to follow the instruction to go to MavensMate --> Settings --> **Users**, but only options that I have are:

Global Settins, User Plugin Settings, Default Plugin Settings and Setting Help.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: I met the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: Sorry I did not pursue after this.

Comment: Seems like it doesn't need setting user anymore in latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Settings > User Plugin Settings then in the document you will see an import note at the top which says that some settings are in the Maven Desktop. So you need to go to MavensMate > Settings > Global Settings for more information then edit the path in there on the Maven Desktop.